# Unexpected extra characters in file written with RandomAccessFile.writeBytes()

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to write(and read) string to file using the "RandomAccessFile", but "fio.writeBytes(file1str)" adds the some garbage at the end of the string:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the D of planets: ");
        file1str = in.readLine();
        fio = new RandomAccessFile(new File("file1"), "rw");
        fio.writeBytes(file1str);
        System.out.println("Your enter: ");
        for (String retval: file1str.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(retval);
        }
        fio.close();
        System.out.println("Data saves to 'file1'!");
 }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error1");
    }


}
```

[image]

....But if we are open the file, we see additional 10700 at the end:
[image]

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your code look fine , its working in my environment , try to in.close(); after reading line

Comment: Above code snippet should work as you expected. Are you sure you are not writing anything to the file after this code. Can you post the full class here?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `RandomAccessFile` with mode = "rw", the documentation says "If the file does not already exist then an attempt will be made to create it."

This means that if the file already exists, then no attempt will be made to create it, delete it, truncate it, etc.

So, what is happening is that for whatever reason, you already have a "file1" which has 9 characters in it, and what your code does is that it only overwrites the first 4 characters. (The "5,10" part.)

Try deleting the file before writing to it, and everything should be fine.

<sub>Alternatively, consider the possibility that choosing a `RandomAccessFile` was a bad idea to begin with, and instead try using `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))`, to write a normal text file the normal way that normal people normally use.</sub>

Comment: @PavelS. thanks for contributing.  However, I was looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String) and I could not find any mention of a "+" character for the mode argument.  Are you sure?